# pydantic not found in FastApi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jwt, fastapi, pydantic

I downloaded some libraries using the following command -

`$ pip3 install "passlib[bcrypt]" SQLAlchemy "fastapi[all]" pyjwt`

When I tried to import the python library pydantic it wasn't found, and when I tried to download that library again it showed me that I already have that in the project.

It happens to me with other libraries like fastapi, jwt

screenshots-
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPnpU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhnsg.png)

I tried to delete my virtual environment and re-installed it with all the packages.
I checked that the path of my packages is in my venv in the lib folder.

Comment: I assume you are calling `pip3 install` from within the virtual environment and executing your code in the environment?

Comment: @Tim Yes I did ```pip3 install``` and tried to install all the libraries separately

Comment: But did you do it _in the same environment_ as vscode uses? (i.e. the environment that vscode has been configured to use)